# Postgres - how to check how much OS space can be recovered

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have a huge tables where a lot of DELETEs are being made.
From time to time Im vacuuming tables to restore some space back to the system, by executing below

```
  VACUUM FULL VERBOSE ANALYSE table_name
```

I know autovacuum should do the job, but I cant see any space usage reduction over the time.
Full Vacuum it is apparently quite long process and sometimes I realize it wasnt worth effort, because I recoverd only fre Gigs. Other times I can get dozen of space

So I wonder if there is any way to check in Postgres how much space can be released back to OS before any operation are taken / which tables need vacuuming

Im using version 12.

**** Edit ****

In short I need rough estimate of wasted space I can get back after vacuuming.

Comment: Although I think that my answer is correct for rough estimations - I would look for more precise/correct answer on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about "released back to OS".

But for rough estimate of wasted space I would do:

```sql
SELECT 
        schemaname , relname , 
        pg_total_relation_size(relid) AS total_size,
        n_live_tup , n_dead_tup , 
        n_dead_tup * 100.0 / 
        CASE n_live_tup WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE n_live_tup END  AS dead_ratio,
        pg_total_relation_size(relid) * n_dead_tup  / CASE n_live_tup WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE n_live_tup END AS wasted_space
    FROM 
        pg_catalog.pg_stat_all_tables 
    WHERE
        schemaname = 'public'
    ORDER BY 
        wasted_space DESC;
```

| schemaname | relname | total_size | n_live_tup | n_dead_tup | dead_ratio | wasted_space |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| public | page_extract | 409575424 | 92428 | 5831 | 6.3086943350499849 | 25838861 |
| public | annotation_type | 761856 | 1 | 6 | 600.0000000000000000 | 4571136 |
| public | doc_dflt | 38010880 | 15789 | 1120 | 7.0935461397175249 | 2696319 |
| public | page | 215359488 | 215567 | 1650 | 0.76542327907332755014 | 1648411 |
| public | file | 17784832 | 12995 | 1027 | 7.9030396306271643 | 1405542 |

Logic:

- get ratio of dead tuples
- multiply on relation size

Of course it's a very rough estimation, real results will vary.

Comment: Thanks @Alex You  - indeed Im looking for waste space potentially I can get back. Executing your query No1 on list I can see pg_toast - what is that ? can I get this space back ?

Comment: [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/storage-toast.html) is where postgresql stores data that exceeds page size of 8Kb. E.g. content of text/binary/xml/json fields most probably will be in pg_toast. They are not independent objects - deleteing/vacuuming tables will lead to freeing space in TOAST.

Comment: if there no dead tuples but a lot of space where they once were, how does this work?